# DrRacket autocomplete does not see functions defined in my source code

Tags: racket

I am using Racket and DrRacket for a small project (I am trying to learn both and using them to teach a friend of mine some functional programming).

I have just discovered the autocomplete function (C-/) and it works fine with library functions, but it won't see my own functions.

I have also added

```
(provide (all-defined-out))
```

at the beginning of my source file (I thought that the autocomplete function might not see the symbols because they are not exported) but this does not solve the problem.

All the symbols are accessible in the DrRacket REPL (I can evaluate my functions and they work fine).

Can you give me any indication on how to solve this problem? Do I need to configure something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can confirm that DrRacket currently works this way. The best advice I can give, is to submit a feature request (use "Submit Bugreport" in the Help menu) and then cross your fingers.

Comment: Do you mean that DrRacket only "sees" library symbols and that making other symbols accessible would be a new features?

Comment: Yes, that's what it means.

Comment: Note that if you click the "Delta" icon (next to the "save" icon) you will get a list of definitions in the current file. In other words: The information is available in the system, it just isn't hooked up to the autocomplete yet.

Comment: Is there another racket IDE supports that feature? I read the [document mentioned several LISP modes](https://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/Emacs.html) like Racket-mode and Geiser, do they support this feature?